# Win2003 logs off a disconnected session

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

We have a need to have a semi-permanent terminal session open.  I have configured group policy to never log off any session, even if it's disconnected.  It is still logging off, though.  I have followed the following article from MS:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_2

Everything I see on Google points to these same steps.  Anything I'm missing?

[image]
Note: the time limits are enabled but set to "never"

[image]

RSOP:

```
    Administrative Templates
    ------------------------
        GPO: Local Group Policy
            KeyName:     SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\MaxIdleTime
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            KeyName:     SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\KeepAliveInterval
            Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            KeyName:     SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\KeepAliveEnable
            Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            KeyName:     SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\MaxDisconnectionTime
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            KeyName:     SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\fResetBroken
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled
        GPO: Local Group Policy
            KeyName:     SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\MaxConnectionTime
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled
```

Comment: Is the Group Policy actually applying? Have you tried a gpresult to see if it is?

Comment: @Cole, Yes. see edit to my post.

Comment: How does your utilization of CALs for TS look? Have you possibly hit the limit - then when a user connects it bumps the idle session?

Comment: @Cole: if I connect to it several times it won't be booted.

Comment: @TheCleaner: There's a note in my post stating that they are set to "never".

Comment: ah...sorry skipped right over that.  Delete your latest comment and I'll remove this one.

Comment: In active directory there are also per user settings for logging off on the Sessions tab.  Have you checked there?

Comment: @Grant, if that shows up in RSOP then it's not there.  Also we had this same user running disconnected indefinitely on another server until Friday.